# Ignore `/static` when URL pattern absorbs it

Tags: python, django, apache, url, url-routing

I am serving my static files at `example.com/static/`. I am also using the following url pattern in my root url conf (pointed at `example.com`) which absorbs everything in order to include some things at the root:

`url(r'^', include('ecore.urls', namespace="ecore")),`

**ecore.urls:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^tags/(?P<tag_slug>[\w-]*)', views.tag_view, name='tag_view'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about_view, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact_view, name='contact'),
)
```

This is a problem as all my static files return a `404`.

This was not an issue in my development as I was using `example.com/dev/` and so that pattern didn't chew everything up.

Negative lookaheads (`(?!static/)`) can not be parsed for a url pattern. Is there some sort of ignore pattern?

---

The static files are served by using `collecstatic` to put the files in `www/static/` and then apache `Options -Indexes` so people do not go exploring.

The site is set up to point at the root which is basically `www/`.

Comment: Put your "static/" rule below the other rules

Comment: @Joucks I have no "static/" pattern. What would it be since they are served by apache and not django?

Comment: Ok sorry, I get it now. So maybe configure your webserver to not use django for the `example.com/static/` urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If requests for static files are returning a 404 in production, then you have Apache configured incorrectly: your HTTP server should handle requests for `/static/` without getting your Django application involved at all. There is an example Apache config [in the Django documentatio](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/).

Make sure that the `Alias /static` is in your config before the `WSGIScriptAlias /`.

If requests for static files are returning a 404 in development, then you can explicitly add the staticfiles handler:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns(…)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + urlpatterns
```

(see also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Django doesn't have any sort of "ignore this URL pattern" facility. After all, what does it mean to ignore a URL pattern? By the time Django is handling a request, the HTTP server is expecting a response, and there is no standard (or even Apache-specific) way for Django to tell Apache "actually I don't want to handle this request, pass it along".

Comment: I am moving to production and so `DEBUG = False`. It seems that `static()` is for serving static when I already have a solution for that. The example is basically my setup except I do not have to alias `/static` somewhere as it is already at `www/static/`. How do I configure Apache to not use Django for `/static/` so that it never goes to django?

Comment: Ah, that's your problem, then :) You need the explicit alias, otherwise Apache will pass all the requests to Django (because of `WSGIScriptAlias /`).

Comment: Just added the alias: `Alias /static /var/www/static/` and it seems to work just great! Update your answer.